# Send Data between client and server as a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, networking, encryption

I am trying to send encrypted data between a client and server. Due to the RSA encryption its in Byte array form. This means I have had to change the way I send data. I curently cant get it working, Ill leave my method (sendMessage) below which is what handles the sending of the message, If anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong that would be great :)

```
 public void sendMessage(byte[] msg){ 
        if(msg.equals("null")){
                
                
        }        
        else{
            try{
            ByteArrayOutputStream f = new ByteArrayOutputStream(CSocket.getOutputStream());
            out = new PrintWriter(f);
            out.write(msg);
            countSend++;
            }catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
        }       
 
    }
```

Sorry should have clarified, essentially CSocket is a socket I have opend and I want to send msg through the socket. The issue I have specifically with this code is It says that:  `OutputStream can not be converted to int` on the line where I creat the `ByteArrayOutputStream` object `f` and `No suitable method found for write(byte[])` on the line `out.write(msg);`

Comment: Could you please describe what you would expect to happen and what actually is happening?

Comment: Hi I added some more detail above. Essentially I call this method to send off the byte array msg to the client/server on the other side of the connection. I would expect the byte array would be displayed on the other connected machine, but currently I get the error I have now stated above. Any help will be much appreaciated @KajHejer

Comment: I'm not sure why you are messing with `ByteArrayOutputStream` here, it doesn't do anything you want. Just use the correct method of `OutputStream` to send the bytes.

Comment: Cheers mate that helped a bit, Im still not sure how to format the `out.write` but Im working on it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed my issue now. Its probibably not the most efficient way of doing it but essentially I encode the byte array in a format that means I wont loose any data. This means I send it in this encoded format and then on the receving end I just simply decode it. Works so much better with print writer doing it this way.

```
OutputStream f = CSocket.getOutputStream();
out = new PrintWriter(f);
String encodedmsg = new String(msg, "ISO-8859-1"); // ISO-8859-1 is supposed to give every character a unique representation so I shouldent loose any data during encoding and decoding
out.write(encodedmsg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarification! Please see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#write(byte%5B%5D,int,int)

The write method in ByteArrayOutputStream for byte[] needs two more arguments. Something like the following might work:

```
out.write(msg, 0, msg.length);
```

Please let me know if this is useful.

Comment: The constructor of ByteArrayOutputStream only accepts an int parameter. You probably meant `ByteArrayOutputStream f = CSocket.getOutputStream();`

Comment: So, I have tried entering `ByteArrayOutputStream f = CSocket.getOutputStream();` and I have also changed the out.write to `out.write(msg, 0, msg.length)` . The issue with the first change is that it states `output stream can not be converted to byte output stream` and the second issue is `no suitable method found for write(byte[],int,int)` That second error I dont understand as In the document it litterally states it wants it in that format `public void write​(byte[] b, int off, int len)`. Cheers for the help so far guys, much appreaciated :)

Comment: This seems to work `ByteArrayOutputStream f = (ByteArrayOutputStream) CSocket.getOutputStream();` But I dont know really what this format dose aha.*edit - This definately dosent work doing this, I dont know what I was thinking

Comment: Good to see it goes the right way :) Does the write method also work now after the last change?

Comment: Not yet, Im playing with it at the moment, Im not sure why its not liking the format you suggested.

Comment: OK, keep us posted :)

Comment: So far no luck sadly, I have been scouring the internet and trying small tweaks like `int Length = msg.length;
out.write(msg, 0, Length);` But that didnt work, I have found this just now but I dont know if it really matches my needs : https://www.baeldung.com/java-convert-byte-array-to-writer